# unable to deploy WAR file via git in openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to deploy a pre compiled WAR file to my openshift application and its failing with below error

`remote: Not a directory - /var/lib/openshift/XXXXXXXXXXXX/app-deployments/ROOT.war/metadata.json`

What is this `metadata.json` file ?
What should be inside it ? 
Should this file be changed every time i try to deploy new WAR file ?

I couldn't find any info on openshift wiki's for these questions

I would be happy to know how to deploy a binary directly without git too. I get following error when trying to deploy WAR file by `rhc app deploy` command.

`No such file or directory - /var/lib/openshift/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/app-deployments/2014-06-15_12-50-12.137/metadata.json`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can deploy WAR file. One that uses Git another that don't uses Git. If you want to use Git way, then place your WAR file in your app Git repo deployments or webapp directory. Then add it and then push the changes to application Git repository.

Other option to do binary deployment is mentioned below:

1. Create an OpenShift app using the command `rhc app-create myapp jbosseap --no-git`
2. Then enable binary deployment `rhc configure-app --app myapp --no-auto-deploy --deployment-type binary`
3. Create a directory structure `mkdir binary-deployment && cd binary-deployment/ && mkdir -p build-dependencies/.m2 repo/deployments dependencies/jbosseap/deployments`
4. Place your WAR file in repo/deployments folder
5. Package the archive `tar -czvf ../myapp-archive.tar.gz ./`
6. Deploy the new binary artifact using `rhc deploy --app myapp --ref ../myapp-archive.tar.gz command`

Comment: I tried your steps and I still get error


Deployment of file 'myapp/myapp-archive.tar.gz' in progress for application myapp ...
Starting deploy for binary artifact
Stopping gear
Creating new deployment directory
No such file or directory - /var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/app-deployments/2014-06-16_23-47-35.043/metadata.json
Error deploying local file. You can try to deploy manually with:
ssh -t XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@myapp.rhcloud.com 'oo-binary-deploy'
SSH command finished with exit status = 255

Comment: what would be the folder name if I am using `wildfly` instead of `jbosseap`?